# Inno Setup: add a second custom input page (first one works well

Tags: input, inno-setup

With the help of the experts on this forum, I use this code to add a custom input page to an Inno Setup script:

```
[Code]

var
  UserInputsPage: TInputQueryWizardPage;

function GetWatchFolder(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := UserInputsPage.Values[0];
end;

[Code]

procedure InitializeWizard;

var  
  dfPath: string; 
begin

  dfPath := 'C:\TEMP';
  RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, 'SOFTWARE\WPDOS.org', 'FilePrintPath', dfPath );

  { Create the page }
  UserInputsPage :=
    CreateInputQueryPage(wpWelcome,
      'Folder to watch', 'Enter the path to the folder that you want me to watch. I will create it if it does not exist.',
      'Please type a folder path, then click Next.');
  UserInputsPage.Add('Folder to watch:', False);
  UserInputsPage.Values[0] := dfPath;
end;
```

I am now trying to add a second page to ask for a second input (another folder name). I've written the following code, and when I add it beneath the existing code (shown above), the compiler doesn't complain, but the new page does not appear when the script is run.

Obviously I'm leaving out some simple and obvious step that will display the second page, but that step isn't obvious to me. I would be very grateful if someone could tell me what that obvious step should be. I've been experimenting for hours without success. Here's that second block of code:

```
[Code]

var
  UserInputsPage2: TInputQueryWizardPage;

function GetPdfPathFolder(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := UserInputsPage2.Values[0];
end;

[Code]

var  
  pdfPath: string; 

begin

  pdfPath := '';
  RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, 'SOFTWARE\WPDOS.org', 'pdfPath', pdfPath );

  { Create the page }
  UserInputsPage2 :=
     CreateInputQueryPage(wpWelcome,
      'Folder for saved PDFs', 'By default I will save PDFs to the desktop. If you want to us a different folder, enter its path here. I will create it if it does not exist.',
      'Please type a folder path, then click Next.');
  UserInputsPage2.Add('Folder for saved PDFs (leave blank to use desktop):', False);
  UserInputsPage2.Values[0] := pdfPath;
end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your code does because you didn't provide a full example.  This code works for me using your code as a base.  Using `wpWelcome` for both `CreateInputQueryPage` calls worked too but my example seems cleaner. I'm using InnoSetup 6.0.3(u).

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "My Program"
#define MyAppVersion "1.5"
#define MyAppPublisher "My Company, Inc."
#define MyAppURL "http://www.example.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "MyProg.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application. Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{380D65F4-34C6-4E55-B806-1EE46EEBD2B6}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={autopf}\{#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
; Uncomment the following line to run in non administrative install mode (install for current user only.)
;PrivilegesRequired=lowest
OutputBaseFilename=mysetup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
WizardStyle=modern

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 6\Examples\MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{autoprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{autodesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent

[Code]

var
  UserInputsPage: TInputQueryWizardPage;
  UserInputsPage2: TInputQueryWizardPage;
  pdfPath: string; 

 function GetPdfPathFolder(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := UserInputsPage2.Values[0];
end;


function GetWatchFolder(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := UserInputsPage.Values[0];
end;

[Code]

procedure InitializeWizard;

var  
  dfPath: string; 
begin

  dfPath := 'C:\TEMP';
  RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, 'SOFTWARE\WPDOS.org', 'FilePrintPath', dfPath );

  { Create the page }
  UserInputsPage :=
    CreateInputQueryPage(wpWelcome,
      'Folder to watch', 'Enter the path to the folder that you want me to watch. I will create it if it does not exist.',
      'Please type a folder path, then click Next.');
  UserInputsPage.Add('Folder to watch:', False);
  UserInputsPage.Values[0] := dfPath;
  pdfPath := '';
  RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, 'SOFTWARE\WPDOS.org', 'pdfPath', pdfPath );

  { Create the page }
  UserInputsPage2 :=
     CreateInputQueryPage(UserInputsPage.ID,
      'Folder for saved PDFs', 'By default I will save PDFs to the desktop. If you want to us a different folder, enter its path here. I will create it if it does not exist.',
      'Please type a folder path, then click Next.');
  UserInputsPage2.Add('Folder for saved PDFs (leave blank to use desktop):', False);
  UserInputsPage2.Values[0] := pdfPath;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you! This is just perfect. What I want to do with the entered value is write a value to the registry, and this makes it entirely possible for me to do it. Your code also helps me understand the structure of the [Code] section in a way I didn't before. Again, many thanks!